# seperate titles of multiples plots in R

Tags: r, boxplot, par, oma

I plot 5 boxplots (boxplot) in two rows with `par(mfrow = c(2,5), oma = c(0,0,2,2))`.

```
par(mfrow = c(2,5),oma = c(0, 2, 2, 0))
boxplot(x,...)
title (main = "title1", outer = T)
boxplot(y,...)
title (main = "title2", outer = T)#overwrites title 1
```

how to place the title2 above the 2nd row of boxplots?

Comment: I would really recommend to use a different plot package that supports some kind of multi-facet plot, e.g. `lattice` or `ggplot2`. My suggestion is `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mtext` to plot the title wherever you want.

```
data("mtcars")
par(mfrow = c(2,5),oma = c(0, 2, 2, 0))
replicate(10,boxplot( mpg~cyl,mtcars))
mtext("title1",line = 0,outer=T,font = 2)
mtext("title2",line = -24,outer=T,font = 2)
```

[image]